# Python sendmail with Cc

Tags: python

I already programmed a function which sends mails with atachments, images on text and other things, but now I need the function to use de Cc (Carbon Copy) function in order to send copies to different emails.

I have done some changes on the function and it works but not as I want.

THe email is sent to the address ("toaddr") and the mail shows that there are other emails added as Cc("tocc") emails, but the Cc emails do not recieve the email.

To be more clear (because I think I am not being very clear) here is an example:

```
Sender: from@hotmail.com
Receiver: to@hotmail.com
Copied: cc@hotmail.com

to@hotmail.com receives the email and can see that cc@hotmail.com is copied on it.
cc@hotmail.com does not get the email.
if to@hotmail.com reply to all the email, THEN cc@hotmail gets the email.
```

Can anyone help me telling me what do I need to change on the function?? I guees the problem is with the `server.sendmail()` function

This is my function:

```
def enviarCorreo(fromaddr, toaddr, tocc, subject, text, file, imagenes):
    msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = ','.join(toaddr)
    msg['Cc'] = ','.join(tocc)         # <-- I added this
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg.attach(MIMEText(text,'HTML'))
    #Attached Images--------------
    if imagenes:
       imagenes = imagenes.split('--')
       for i in range(len(imagenes)):   
        adjuntoImagen = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
        adjuntoImagen.set_payload(open(imagenes[i], "rb").read())
        encode_base64(adjuntoImagen)
        anexoImagen = os.path.basename(imagenes[i])
        adjuntoImagen.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename= "%s"' % anexoImagen)
        adjuntoImagen.add_header('Content-ID','<imagen_%s>' % (i+1))
        msg.attach(adjuntoImagen)   
    #Files Attached ---------------
    if file:
       file = file.split('--')
       for i in range(len(file)):
        adjunto = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
        adjunto.set_payload(open(file[i], "rb").read())
        encode_base64(adjunto)
        anexo = os.path.basename(file[i])
        adjunto.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename= "%s"' % anexo)
        msg.attach(adjunto)
    #Send ---------------------
    server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    server.set_debuglevel(1)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr,[toaddr,tocc], msg.as_string())    #<-- I modify this with the tocc
    server.quit()
    return
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your sendmail call, you're passing `[toaddr, tocc]` which is a list of lists, have you tried passing `toaddr + tocc` instead?